# how to pass RouteData via Router.navigate in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there an api in agnular2 that allows passing json objects instead of string values . E.g. In `Router.navigate()` I can pass route parameters

```
Router.navigate('routename',[{key:stringvalue}])
```

and can retrieve it using `RouteParams.get(key) : string`.
But this returns just string values. I need to pass the json object.

Appreciate any pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it's not something possible out of the box since routing relies on URLs and both path variables and query parameters are strings. Both [`RouterParams`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteParams-class.html) and [`RouterData`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteData-class.html) only supports string attributes.

To simulate this, I don't see other solutions than encoding your JSON objects using `JSON.stringify` and parsing them on the other side.

Here is a plunkr describing this: https://plnkr.co/edit/jbl7v5fHQEmf4F8tpXDO?p=preview.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: RouterParams and RouterData are not part of @angular/router any more.

Answer (score 7):

Another Solution that works is using the `params` Property of RouterParams.
This may not be the preferred way, but it works (as of Beta8).

if you navigate with `Router.navigate(['/myRoute',{someProperty:"SomeValue"}]`
you can access the param with:

```
constructor(routeParams: RouteParams){
  let myPassedData: any = routeParams.params;
  console.log(myPassedData.someProperty); #Prints "SomeValue"
}
```

Comment: Hey @Chris. How do i import `RouteParams` ?

Comment: afaik RouteParams was superseded by `ActivatedRoute`, which gives you access to the route and its params

Answer (score 0):

For Angualr 7,8+:

sending end:

```
this.router.navigate(['/targeturl/' , JSON.stringify(inputParameter)]);
```

receiveing end:

```
import {  ActivatedRoute,  Router} ....

 sub;
  ngOnInit() {

this.sub = this.activatedroute.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  console.log(params);
  debugger;
  }); }
```