# How to get Multiple parameter in other component in angular 2

Tags: angular2-routing

This is a function in one ts file where I am passing latitude and longitude. Now I have to get these lat long in other component so how to get these parameter in other component.

```
routeWithData(id, latitude, longitude)
   {   
      //console.log(latitude, longitude);
      this.router.navigate(['/provider/bookings/'+id+'/details/map-location/'+latitude+'/'+longitude]);     
   }
```

Comment: You just need to concatenate latitude and longitude with any separator (excluding / and . of course). For example google maps passes coordinates in urls as `@45.4572583,4.4090734`

Comment: How should i do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you navigate with router.navigate(['/someroute',{someProperty:"SomeValue"}]

Follow this:

```
   constructor(routeParams: RouteParams){ let myPassedData: any=routeParams.params;console.log(myPassedData.someProperty); #Prints"SomeValue"}
```

You can get an idea of how to use it from here: 
[how to pass RouteData via Router.navigate in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034840/how-to-pass-routedata-via-router-navigate-in-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate either by passing all parameters in the URL

```
routeWithData(id, latitude, longitude) {   
      //console.log(latitude, longitude);
      this.router.navigate(['/provider/bookings/'+id+'/details/map-location/'+latitude+','+longitude]);     
   }
```

In this case you will have to decode the URL to get the latitude and longitude.

Or you can pass the arguments in the query params:

```
routeWithData(id, latitude, longitude){   
      //console.log(latitude, longitude);
      lat latlon = latitude + ', ' + longitude;
      this.router.navigate(['/provider/bookings/'+id+'/details/map-location/', { queryParams: { latlon: latlon } }]);     
   }
```

See https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments for more details.