# How can I pass data from one component to another for edit form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Currently, I have a modal material dialog window that asks the user to input a number and then hit search. On search, it fetches data from api call and gets back a response object. I want to use the response object to populate a new page (edit form).

My question is, how can I past the data, particularly the number the user entered on the material dialog component to another component, so that it can fetch the api call results or how can I pass my response object to my edit from from dialog?

E.g.

Here's my search function:

```
search(searchNumber) {
    if (this.selectedOption === 'Bill Number') {
      this._transactionService.findExistingTransactionByBillNumber('U001', searchNumber)
                               .subscribe(data => this.transactionResponse = data);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.transactionResponse));

      this.router.navigate(['/edit-transaction-portal']);

    } else {
      this._transactionService.findExistingTransactionByTransactionNumber('U001', searchNumber)
                               .subscribe(data => this.transactionResponse = data);
             console.log(JSON.stringify(this.transactionResponse));
             this.router.navigate(['/edit-transaction-portal']);
      }
    }
```

I want to be able to either 1) pass the response object I get here or pass the searchNumber the user entered, so that I can do a lookup within my edit form component. I need to pass in either one from this component to my new component that I navigate to.

EDIT: Accepted solution shows how to add query params to this.router.navigate() and how to retrieve it by subscribing to activateRoute, a different approach than the one identified in the other SO post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass RouteData via Router.navigate in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35034840/how-to-pass-routedata-via-router-navigate-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the number (bill/transaction)

```
this.router.navigate(['/edit-transaction-portal'], { queryParams: { bill: 'U001' } });
this.router.navigate(['/edit-transaction-portal'], { queryParams: { transaction: 'U001' } });
```

then in your `component(edit-transaction-portal)` hit the api to get the data. In component you should include `ActivatedRoute` in constructor. It will be something like:

```
isBill: boolean;
isTransaction: boolean;
number: string;
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.isBill = params['bill'] != undefined;
        this.isTransaction = params['transaction'] != undefined;
        this.number = this.isBill ? params['bill'] : params['transaction'];
        // Call API here
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, how can I past the data, particularly the number the
>   user entered on the `material dialog component` to another component

You can pass it throw material dialog component. Inject dialogRef to you component which opened in the dialog:

```
constructor(
   public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SomeComponent>,   
   @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,    
  ) { }
```

After the submitting data, you can pass any data to component which opened this dialog, by closing the dialog:

```
  onSubmit() {
    this.service.postProduct(this.contract, this.product)
      .subscribe(resp => {
        this.dialogRef.close(resp);
      });

  }
```

And in your Parent component, who opened this dialog can get this passed data by subscribing to `afterClosed()` observable:

**Parent.component.ts:**

```
openDialog(id) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SomeComponent, {

      data: { id: anyData}
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
         // do something...
      }
    });
  }
```

> Would I pass the data object in dialog.open()? How would I retrieve it
>   from there?

Look at `openDialog()` above. It has `data` property, that you can send to dialog components. And in the opened component inject `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` as this:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
```

to access passed `data` object as shown code above

[Official docs[sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component]](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-)

Comment: Thanks. What about vice versa? From main component to dialog (where main component calls dialog). Would I pass the data object in dialog.open()? How would I retrieve it from there?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass data which the help of routing you have to define route which takes value as part of rout like as below

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },];
```

it will from code side

```
gotoHeroes(hero: Hero) {
  let heroId = hero ? hero.id : null;
  // Pass along the hero id if available
  // so that the HeroList component can select that hero.
  // Include a junk 'foo' property for fun.
  this.router.navigate(['/heroes', { id: heroId, foo: 'foo' }]);
}
```

Read : https://angular.io/guide/router#router-imports

---

If you want to pass data between two component then there is `@Input` and `@Output` property concept in angular which allows you to pass data between components.

`@Input()` - this type of property allows you to pass data from parent to child component.

`Output()` - this type of property allows you to pass data from child to parent component.

---

Other way to do it is make use of `Service` as use the same instance of service between component.

Read : [3 ways to communicate between Angular components](https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb)

Comment: You can't use intput, output with routing.

Comment: @Dhavalkansagara - misunderstood question , thanks for pointing update my answer